# how to execute a function with the same name as variable evaluates in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have array which contains laravel model (`App\User`) attribute names like following:

```php
$documents = array(
      'passport_expire' => 22,
      'residency' => 13
      );
```

If I called these functions directly it will return a boolean value like:

```php
App\User::find(2)->passport_expire;//will output true / false
```

I want to execute the functions inside a `foreach`:

```php
foreach($documents as $type => $val){
// I want to call the attributes
App\User::find(1)->{$type};
//I want to call and execute App\User::find(1)->passport_expire and App\User::find(1)->residency
```

I read in php documentation about a way with similar approach called [Variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) but I don't know how to accomplish that in laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
App\User::find(1)->$type;
```

Also you want to use string & variable

```
App\User::find(1)->$type . '_test';
```

However, if you want to use string as first, I think you need to create a variable beforehand and use first approach.

```
$type = "xx_$type_xx"
App\User::find(1)->$type;
```

---

Whereas, `App\User::find(1)->{$type};` works,

But  `App\User::find(1)->{$type . 'text'};` doesn't work.

Comment: What if I want to append a string to the variable and execute the attribute like: `App\User::find(1)->{$type}'_date';//so it will execute App\User::find(1)->passport_expire_date`

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the attributes/properties as functions?

So far I think you meant [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

If you want to access the properties like `passport_expire` or `residency` then you can try like

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
foreach  (array_keys($documents) as $document) {
    $documents[$document] = $user->{$document};
}
```

The above code will update the `$documents` array with the values of `$user` object's properties.

But, if you want to execute as **functions** as you mentioned, you need to try [call_user_func](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) or [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)